Cleaning shower - acid or alkaline detergent first?
I have acid detergent to get rid of mineral buildup and alkaline solution for all the grease.
But which one should I use first?

Routinely get rid of grease with an alkali cleaner – once a week, or after every use? And occasionally use an acid to remove the mineral deposits – once a month? Don't use them at the same time – make sure you showered in between to rinse it down thoroughly.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Acid.
The soaps and detergents that you have been using every day in your shower are alkaline. So the acid cleaner will have a more dramatic effect than the alkaline cleaner.

The remnants left from soap buildup, where tap-water is acid, in particular, are fats and fatty acids that need to be removed with alkaline cleaners.

It makes no difference which is used first, since there are layers of crud to be removed.

Clean with mild acid cleaner (e.g., tub cleaner with sulfamic acid) to remove buildup of lime and metal salts, or with alkaline detergent to remove fats and fatty acids from soap.
Rinse thoroughly.
Use the complementary cleaner.
Rinse again.
Reiterate until satisfied.

However, you might need stain removers if stains have soaked in.

Reducing chemicals, such as sodium bisulfite (e.g., Red-b-Gone)
Oxidizing chemicals, such as chlorine bleach

For all cleaners, use with caution.
